# Applying formula based on condition in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I have numpy array:

`wk = np.array([1, 0, 3, -4])`

how to apply a formula based on certain condition, like how to sum all positive value in `wk`. I've tried

```
if wk.all > 0:
    np.sum(wk)
```

But it threw an error.

Comment: what does the error say?

Comment: `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
np.sum(wk[wk > 0])
```

is what you are looking for. `wk > 0` creates a boolean array of the same size as `wk` that is true everywhere where `wk > 0`. `wk[wk > 0]` then evaluates to an array that only contains those elements of `wk` where the former array is true and finally `np.sum` sums up those values.

Answer (score 1):

for the positive values you can use:

```
import numpy as np
wk = np.array([1, 0, 3, -4])
sum = wk[wk>0].sum() # returns array of elements which are positive and then adds them
```

similarly you can put conditions inside wk[condition_here]